# phpMyadmin - multiple databases login re-requested

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, replication

I have installed phpMyAdmin on a replicated MySQL set up where PMA is installed on the master DB host. The PMA config file lists the master and slave hosts in the $cfg['Servers'] array as follows:-

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']   = 'Database name';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'IP address of host';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

This produces a selection list when logging in and also when logged in in the top LHS of the PMA UI.

If I log into 'DB Host 1' and then once logged in I subsequently select 'DB Host 2' the main login form is presented so I can then log in and view the database for the 'DB Host 2'. If I then decide to switch back to 'DB Host 1' I then get the main login screen again and I have to log in again.. I was expecting the original login cookie to be valid still for 'DB Host 1' thus preventing an additional login process.

Is it possible to only have to log in once onto each configured DB Host and the login credentials are valid for the session?

I hope i have explained the above clearly!

Comment: You're going to need to give more context because that snippet only shows some random bits of data, not how it's used, nor what your intention is with that data.

Comment: I'm not sure what more you need? The snippet is not random as it shows the PMA connection settings for all the database hosts and the issue is I have to login again each time I select a different database despite having logged in before so it relates to the connection settings. Let me know what extra information you are expecting and I will provide it. Thanks!